# floating div effects the height of other div in my screen

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

Look at my html + css code: http://jsfiddle.net/nP39E/1/

I'll explain if don't understand what I want to achieve:

I want a page with a div which floating right and takes 250px width and a div that takes width of the rest of the document.

In the left div, you can see that I have some other floating elements, and their heights are effected from the right div. You can see the first (red) row with height that align with the right bar's height and has nothing to do with the real content of its content.

- I use group class in order to handle the common floating problem: `.group:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; }`

Can you tell me why it happens?

Comment: It happens because you're using `table` display settings. Why do you need things set to `display: table`?

Comment: @helion3 this is the "clearfix/group" class, I use it in order to solve the common floating problem, to force 2 elements be in the same line... http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I just changed CSS for the content div from the last answer:

```
.content {
    background: #888;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 270px;
    left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nP39E/4/

What you think?

Answer (score -1):

`display: table` isn't meant to be used for layouts like this, it's more useful for specific equal-height situations.

Properly floating the divs and not using the `margin-right` to push the left div will work:

```
.content {
    background: #888;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nP39E/2/)

Answer (score -1):

You are giving margin-right:270px which is wider than the available space,So just remove that. Also you should make content float:left.

```
.content {
    background: #888;
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/nP39E/3/